# A command-line or batch cmd to concatenate multiple files with multiple new lines

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

I need a .bat file which concatenates multiple files with multiple new lines

For example

file1.txt:

```
A
```

file2.txt:

```
B
```

file3.txt:

```
C
```

After running the batch script, a new file called Merge.txt will contain the contents:

```
A
    
(I want several blanks that I can set up)
    
B

(I want the new line to be between each file)

C
```

I've seen many questions and answers, but I don't know how to make several new lines. And I don't know how to convert that command into a bat file.

```
copy /b *.txt newfile.txt

type *.txt > newfile.txt

FOR %f IN (*.txt) DO type %f >> newfile.log & echo. >> newfile.log
```

I know above command lines. But I can't make this.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. We're not a "please write me a script" kind of service. If you share your script, we'll let you know what needs to be edited in order to get it to work. A batchfile is nothing more than a textfile. Each letter in the batchfile is executed when you doubleclick it, as if it was typed directly into cmd, including the enter. So new lines transmit the enter in your script.

Comment: Hi. and I'm sorry to ask a question that doesn't fit the site format. I thought I just had to paste the command to create batch files. But it wasn't made differently from what I thought, so I posted it to see how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I got you want to merge several text files and choose the number of lines there should be between each of them right? Look if it is this you want. You have to drag and drop the folder where the text files are to the batch file.

[ConcatenateTXTAndLines.gif](https://s10.gifyu.com/images/ConcatenateAndLines.gif)

```
@echo off

if exist "%~1" If not exist "%~1\" exit

set "Folder=%~1"
echo.
set /p "BLines=How many Blank lines do you want: "

set /a BLines+=1

if /i exist "%~dp0Merge.txt" del /q "%~dp0Merge.txt"

pushd "%Folder%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do call :CreateMainTXT "%%a"

notepad "%~dp0Merge.txt"
exit

:CreateMainTXT
>>"%~dp0Merge.txt" type "%~1"
for /L %%a in (1,1,%BLines%) do >>"%~dp0Merge.txt" echo.
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted. I thought about how to make a program for a few days, and this solved it. Thank you again for explaining it so that I can know even if I don't know it well.

Comment: Glad we could help. Feel free to press the checkbox next to the answer so everyone else knows you no longer need help.

Comment: @Aiden: No problem, that was an easy script to create. Basically the only differance in batch scripts is that you have to use 2 percentage signs where in the command line you would use 1 ex: for %a in -> for %%a in

Comment: I'll take that into consideration and study more. Thank you.